# What are the rules surrounding indentation in python?

Tags: python, indentation

As a beginner in python, I keep getting an indentation error but I am not sure why?

```
>>> gbp_interest = 0.5
>>>
>>> difference_between_pairs = us_interest - gbp_interest
>>> print(abs(difference_between_pairs))
0.3
>>>
>>> if abs(difference_between_pairs) > 0.1 :
... print(max(us_interest, gbp_interest))
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(max(us_interest, gbp_interest))
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Further, is there a reason python is sensitive to indentation (more so then other programming languages)?

Comment: You get an indentation error because your indentation is wrong, and it matters in Python because the designer decided it should.

Comment: Both these questions go back to some very, *very* fundamental Python concepts. If you truly don't have any inkling as to the answers to both of these, you need to go back and read some more fundamental literature on the language itself as it's very clear there are some severe gaps in your lexical understanding. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't conducive to to hand-hold you through your fundamental learning - a simple Google search will yield millions of results which can guide you through these fundamental concepts from a base level (coming from no prior experience at all).

Comment: because the indentation in python is roughly equivalent to `{ }` in c-types languages to define scopes

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is, I would say, the key feature of python.

Indentation helps you define blocks of code. It is to python what `{  }` usually are to some other programming languages.

Indent your `print`:

```py
>>> if abs(difference_between_pairs) > 0.1 :
...     print(max(us_interest, gbp_interest))
```

Consider starting a tutorial, there are plenty of resources on the web.
Example: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, that starter pack is exactly what I needed, sorry for the question